# Formatting table that is filled from a database

Tags: html, css, sql

I have created a table and filled it with information from a database. It currently just lists each row one on top of the other down the web page. I want it to spread across the page before dropping down, but I am having trouble figuring out how to do that.

My Database Table:

```
+---------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| Company       | Name         | Price        | Inventory   |
+---------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| Row1 Company  | Row1 Name    | Row1 Price   | Row1 Inven. |
+---------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| Row2 Company  | Row2 Name    | Row2 Price   | Row2 Inven. |
+---------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
| Row3 Company  | Row3 Name    | Row3 Price   | Row3 Inven. |
+---------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+
```

It displays as follows on the web page:

```
+---------------+
| Row1 Company  |
+---------------+
| Row1 Name     |
+---------------+
| Row1 Price    |
+---------------+
| Row1 Inven.   |
+---------------+
| Row2 Company  |
+---------------+
| Row2 Name     |
+---------------+
| Row2 Price    |
+---------------+
| Row2 Inven.   |
+---------------+
| Row3 Company  |
+---------------+
| Row3 Name     |
+---------------+
| Row3 Price    |
+---------------+
| Row3 Inven.   |
+---------------+
```

This is how I would like it to be presented on the web page. Dropping down to the next "line" once a certain width is reached:

```
+---------------+--------------+--------------+
| Row1 Company  | Row2 Company | Row3 Company |
+---------------+--------------+--------------+
| Row1 Name     | Row2 Name    | Row3 Name    |
+---------------+--------------+--------------+
| Row1 Price    | Row2 Price   | Row3 Price   |
+---------------+--------------+--------------+
| Row1 Inven.   | Row2 Inven.  | Row3 Inven.  |
+---------------+--------------+--------------+
```

I'm sure there is a simple way to do this, but the only think I can think of is to create an html table for each Row of data and then fill the table using a query based on that row's ID. the problem I have with this is that the html file can get quite messy with all those tables being created. (There are 20 rows in my database table so I really don't have to have to create 20 separate html tables if I can avoid it)

This is my current cshtml file:

```
@using PracticeApp.AppCode
@using PracticeApp.AppCode.Entities
@using PracticeApp.Controllers
@model PracticeApp.AppCode.Entities.RetiredDatas

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Retired Equipment";
}

<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
</hgroup>

<div class="products">
    <table>
        @{
            Model.RetiredDataList = Model.RetiredDataList.OrderBy(x => x.Company).ToList();
            foreach(RetiredData row in Model.RetiredDataList)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Company: </b></td>
                    <td>@row.Company</td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Name: </b></td>
                    <td>@row.Name</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Price ($): </b></td>
                    <td>@row.SalePrice</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>Inventory: </b></td>
                    <td>@row.IsSold</td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please tell me... How are you creating this table? How did you `filled it with information from a database` ???

Comment: oh sorry i forgot to post the actual code. my bad. ill post that really quick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the table creation inside the loop, then you can float your tables to put them side-by-side. It will give you the effect you desribed.

Something like this:

```
@{
    Model.RetiredDataList = Model.RetiredDataList.OrderBy(x => x.Company).ToList();
    foreach(RetiredData row in Model.RetiredDataList)
    {
        <table style='float:left;'>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Company: </b></td>
                <td>@row.Company</td>
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td><b>Name: </b></td>
                <td>@row.Name</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Price ($): </b></td>
                <td>@row.SalePrice</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>Inventory: </b></td>
                <td>@row.IsSold</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
}
```

Comment: I have one more question for ya. Is there a way to change the font color of particular items. For instance: `If (isSold = "Sold") {style ="color: red"}`

Comment: Yes! Just put it inside the tag. You can use inline if's, like: `<tr @(row.IsSold == "Sold" ? "style='color:red;'" : "")>` Though remeber that is always better to use css classes instead of inline styles.

Comment: `<td @(row.IsSold == "SOLD" ? "style='color:red;'":"")>@row.IsSold</td>` This is what I have. It didn't change anything.

Comment: Are you sure that `row.IsSold` is a string?

Comment: `public string IsSold { get; set; }` ... Yes :)

Comment: And are you sure that there's any record with the value "SOLD" for `row.IsSold`?

Comment: Yes. I created the database myself. There are 10 rows that have the value "SOLD" for the IsSold column.

Comment: I think it's because of HTML encode that razor does automatically. Try this instead: `<td @(row.IsSold == "SOLD" ? Html.Raw("style='color:red;'") : Html.Raw("")) >@row.IsSold</td>`

Answer (score 0):

keep the foreach like this(to populate  the data)

```
foreach(RetiredData row in Model.RetiredDataList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@row.Company</td>                  
                <td>@row.Name</td>
                <td>@row.SalePrice</td>
                <td>@row.IsSold</td>
            </tr>
        }

  and before foreach do this(to create the header)
          <tr>
                <th><b>Company: </b></th>
                <th><b>Name: </b></th>
                <th><b>Price ($): </b></th>
                <th><b>Inventory: </b></th>
            </tr>
```